# Mount a S3 bucket on Linux without 3rd party tool?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-s3

Is there any way to mount a S3 bucket on the Linux filesystem without any 3rd party tools? Assuming I have a standard Ubuntu installation.

Comment: What definition of "3rd party" do you subscribe to?

Comment: "3rd party" is a poor term. I simply meant anything not part of a basic Ubuntu server installation

Answer (score 1):

No, [s3fs](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=210136&tstart=0) works well.

Comment: [homepage](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/)